# Ember.js cannot access Laravel API

Tags: php, ember.js, laravel-5

I am using ember for front end and Lavarel for API back end.

The problem i am facing is, I have two api say "a" and "b".

I solved the problem "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." with my API "a" by adding CORS to my Laravel project and adding the CORS middleware to my route.

But my another API "b" is also having the same issue even though i added the CORS middleware to route group.

Comment: Did you make sure that the CORS middleware on API "b" is configured properly? You might have a typo in the port, or the accepted origins.

Comment: API "a" and "b" are all in same route group. I applied the middleware to the group not to the individual api